# Automatically install "linux-image" and "linux-headers" on kernel updates

Tags: kernel

I'm using elementary OS 6 Odin. My system just updated to 5.11.0-36-generic kernel.

I do use the manufacturer's wifi driver, specifically broadcom-sta-dkms for BCM43228 model. Since it depends on linux-image and linux-headers to be recompiled, every time the system updates the kernel it goes without network. With no wired network near me, the only choice I have is doing everything offline - a nightmare.

So, there is a way to include linux-image and linux-headers to kernel updates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kernel updates are pushed by Canonical. I have similar problem, because I use dkms drivers and it requires kernel headers to recompile drivers. Hopefully kernel updates are not that common and I just install it manually.

Comment: Absolutely. My issue isn't regarding manual installations - it would be super okay for me, but network loss. I don't have a wired connection available near me, so I cannot apt install the linux-headers/image packages to make it work. Only this month kernel upgraded at least twice. It's frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install a specific version of the kernel header, then the package will not be upgraded (because it's a specific version). However, if you install the generic package, then it will be updated at the same time as an update pulls down the new kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

This should resolve the issue you have after every kernel update

Comment: That's what I was looking for, @matigo. Thank you so much!

Comment: Unfortunately this installs kernel version 5.4, that is default for Ubuntu 20.04, but Odin ships with 5.11. So this solution works for default Ubuntu kernel, but not for the one shipped with eOS.